# Is there a Neovim plugin that can parse a .vscode directory and set up the LSP client accordingly?

Tags: neovim, lsp, vscode

I cloned a project off GitHub recently which comes with a VSCode configuration for telling clangd where all the headers are, providing run configurations etc.  Is there an existing plugin I can download that will let Neovim make use of that configuration, or whatever subset of it makes sense?  I mostly care about clangd args, but run configurations would be nice too.